# error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. usingJsonPlaceHolder

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPZv8.png)
I am trying to run this code but getting errors, can anyone help? I have tried making strings, but still, I get the same error.

error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [world_time] lib\pages\loading.dart:17)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPZv8.png)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {


  void getData() async {
    Response response = await get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    print(response.body);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('loading screen'),
    );
  }?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by using this:

```
Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));
```

OR

```
get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', '/todos/1'));
```